# Add string element from sublists to list by index

Tags: python

I have n list containing strings lists, each of the lists is of equal length. In the first list, each element is a string, but each subsequent list may show null. I would like to check every list, starting from the second one, which elements are not null and add these elements by index to the first list and so to the end of the main list.

Ex:

```
str_list1 = [['1','2','3'],['a',null,'c'],[null,null,'z']]
```

So if string in sublist is not None it should look like that:

```
str_list2 = ['1,a','2','3,c']
```

In the end depends on length of the list it should look like that:

```
str_list2 = ['1,a','2','3,c,z']
```

I would be grateful if someone could help, I'm not new to python but I can't figure it out

Comment: What is `null`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You transpose the list and join each element that's not `None`.

Transpose is a common idiom that looks like this:

```
t = zip(*str_list1)
```

`t` is a generator that returns the tuples `('1', 'a', None)`, `('2', None, None)` and `('3', 'c', 'z')` in order.

You can join a tuple `s` with

```
','.join(x for x in s if x is not None)
```

Combining these two concepts, you get a list comprehension:

```
str_list2 = [','.join(x for x in s if x is not None) for s in zip(*str_list1)]
```

Comment: Surely `t` yields `('2', None, None)` the second time, not `('2',)`